# Magento2.4.5 throws error while di:compile from Inventory module, SourceValidatorInterface not found

Tags: api, inventory, magento2-enterprise, interface, magento2.4.5p1

I upgraded the magento version from 2.3.6-p1 to 2.4.5-p1 for enterprise edition.

While running di:compile, got the following error. Please guide

```
Error: Interface "Magento\InventoryApi\Model\SourceValidatorInterface" not found in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup/Model/Source/Validator/PhoneValidator.php on line 19
```